# getting rid of the `hwatchtvnow` virus

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, malware

My machine appears to be infected with the `search.hwatchtvnow.co` virus.    I get popups from it regularly.      Since I use `chrome`,`firefox` and `opera`, I'm not sure which browser is infected.      There are lots of websites suggesting how to remove it from windows machines, but I can't find anything for linux or ubuntu.      Does anybody have any suggestions?   Thanks!

Comment: I would reset all three browser if I were you

Comment: Yes as @spacelander indicates I would create a new default user or purge all of them making sure the configuration files in your home directory are purged too. Then reinstall.